# How to add an additional label in OpenAM login page

Tags: authentication, customization, openam

I am new to OpenAM. I need to create a custom styled login page, based on an existing login page:

[image: Existing (non OpenAM) login page]

This is what I've got so far:

- I copied the DARK theme
- I modified DataStore1.html to add style-classes and some HTML
- I modified the CSS files

[image: OpenAM version]

My questions:

1. Can I force OpenAM to always show the dutch version, regardless of browser language settings?
2. Where can I change the text of "Sign in"?
3. How do I move the "Remember my username" up so it gets between the username and the password?
4. How can I add the "Log in met je gebruikersnaam en pincode" sub-title?
5. How can I add the "Forgot pincode" URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) You can remove all other localizations for the auth modules and ensure that all default locale properties files (that are involved in authn) are Dutch.

2) This would be in the callback descriptor XML for the authentication module. The DataStore module's XML by default can be found under config/auth/default/DataStore.xml under the servlet context.

3) Probably you will need to write some JavaScript for that. The callback rendering process cannot be customized.

4) In DataStore1.html just add that text above the callback rendering handlebars template (i.e. before {{#each reqs.callbacks}})

5) That depends on what that feature does, if it's just a custom link, then editing the DataStore1.html template will suffice.